# How to detect database new updates in the background and notify user

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I am working on an Android application, it is a news app, the issue is how could I detect that a new news has arrived to the database to notify the user ? I am retrieving data as `JSON Objects`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create an Android Service (that works in background), fetch data from web and update database inside Service. After updating database send a broadcast message to the Activity. If activity is up and running, its broadcast receiver will receive broadcast, then update UI based on the data inside Intent. So simple!

EDIT:

1- Create a Service

1-1- Create a class that extends `Service` class. You can do this with `new android object` wizard.

1-2- Define new `Service` class in your AndroidManifest.xml as below:

```
<service android:name="com.example.MyService"/>
```

1-3- In `onStartCommand` write a code to read server periodically.

1-4- Read [this blog post](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) to get familiar with Android Service.

2- When there is a new data, update database. Then send a broadcast message as below:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.example.action.NEW_DATA_RECEIVED_FROM_SERVER");
i.putExtra("KEY1","VALUE1");
i.putExtra("KEY2","VALUE2");
i.putExtra("KEY3","VALUE3");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

3- Inside your Activity, create a BroadcastReceiver as below:

```
BroadcastReceiver updateReceiver;
```

3-1- Inside onCreate method define your broadcastReceiver:

```
updateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(String action, Intent data) {
        if( action.equals("com.example.action.NEW_DATA_RECEIVED_FROM_SERVER") ) {
           // DO update app
        }
    }
```

3-2- Then in onResume method register this receiver to get "com.example.action.NEW_DATA_RECEIVED_FROM_SERVER" actions as below:

```
registerReceiver(updateReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.action.NEW_DATA_RECEIVED_FROM_SERVER");
```

3-3- inside onPause method:

```
unregisterReceiver(updateReceiver);
```

Also read [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) blog post.

I hope this help!

Comment: I am a beginner and the method you declared above looks to be working but can you give me a showcase or a sample code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Ali that was perfect

Comment: If it is correct anser,mark it as answer to help others who reach this post in the future!

Comment: @AliBehzadianNejad - That is an absolutely perfect answer! Very very very well written.

Comment: HI, what happens if app is not running and I want to hold that data? Does execution of  `onReceive` is guaranteed on App/Activity resume?

Comment: `BroadcastReceiver` is guaranteed to run but it is not an `Activity`. You have to start your Activity on `BroadcastReceiver's` `onReceive` method.

Answer (score 3):

There is no single way to achieve it. But if you want to push directly the news to the user you can consider to use direct [GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) which is replacing C2DM.